# Can I add an out of the box aws_iam_policy (SecurityAudit), an account id and an external id to an aws_iam_role using terraform?

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

I am setting up cloud security and I need to:

1. Select type of trusted entity > Another AWS account
2. Account ID: xxxxxxxxxx
3. External ID: xxxxxxxxxx
4. Attach the SecurityAudit Policy (which is already in AWS)

I'm not sure how to add an already existing policy or where to add the ids. I can't seem to work out a solution from the terraform documentation.

```
../Core/iam_roles.tf

# BEGIN 'foo'
resource "aws_iam_role" "foo" {
  name               = "${terraform.workspace}_Foo"
  path               = "/"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "automation.amazonaws.com",
          "events.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "foo" {
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.security_audit.arn}"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.foo.name}"
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you include the declaration of the resource `aws_iam_policy.security_audit` as well as the error output from `terraform plan` please? That will help in figuring out the error. Also, when you say the "Security Audit" policy is already in AWS, do you mean it is one you have created or it is an AWS provided/managed policy?

Comment: @sarahfiona1, are you trying to do assume this role cross accounts with your first 3 points in your question?  Your current trust policy allows for `automation` and `events` to use this role, you also want another role to assume this one?

Comment: @rclement - SecurityAudit is an AWS provided/managed policy and I have found the policy arn and included this in the policy attachment

Comment: @Tyler Smith - I have added a role manually and copied the json into my code - I will post my solution and it might make more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`# BEGIN 'Foo'
resource "aws_iam_role" "foo" {
  name = "${terraform.workspace}_Foo"
  path = "/"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::INSERT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "INSERT_EXTERNAL_ID"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "foo" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecurityAudit"
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.foo.name}"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "foo" {
  name = "${terraform.workspace}_Foo"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.foo.name}"
}

# END
`
```

Comment: Without a trust policy for EC2, making an instance profile won't do you any good because EC2 can't use it.  You'd need another trust policy with `ec2.amazonaws.com` in it.

    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }

Comment: @tyler smith - Do you think it's necessary to have this? Can I assume 2 role policies in one role?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do.  If you want an EC2 instance to use this role, you absolutely need the EC2 service in the trust policy.  Same applies to any service that you want to use this role.

Comment: @tyler smith - I have sorted this out now and the solution works. The role will be used with 3rd party instances, not my instances and the ID and account number link it to their policy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're attaching a policy that already exists in the account, I would use a data source to query it.  You have to know the ARN to use the IAM policy data source so it's not much different than specifying the ARN directly in the `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` resource except it allows the `terraform plan` command to validate that the policy exists before running `apply`, it's an extra safeguard for you.  The data source also gives you [more information](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy.html#attributes-reference) about the resource should you need it.

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "security_audit" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::${var.target_account_id}:policy/SecurityAudit"
}


# BEGIN 'foo'
resource "aws_iam_role" "foo" {
  name               = "${terraform.workspace}_Foo"
  path               = "/"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "automation.amazonaws.com",
          "events.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::${var.other_aws_account_id}:role/your_role_name_and_path_here"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "foo" {
  policy_arn = "${data.aws_iam_policy.security_audit.arn}"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.foo.name}"
}
```